# Language Translator App in Android

Tags: android

If you have any idea or some reference to make application that allows language translation just like Google translate but here i want to restrict myself to only 2 language.Input language and output language.

Please share your ideas.

Thanks,
Rakesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can use the [Google Translate API](https://developers.google.com/translate/?hl=de).

Answer (score 0):

> The procedure for creating strings.xml files is as follows:
>
> Translate the strings.xml file to each language. Create three new
>   folders under res – values-it, values-fr and values-ru (The original
>   values folder already exists). Place the translated strings.xml files
>   in the respective folders.

Source : [iCanLocalize](http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/android-application-localization-tutorial/).

Also, have a look at the documentation on [Android Localization](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html).

And here is [**another tutorial**](http://www.grammaticalframework.org/android/tutorial/), more suited to your needs!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But i was looking for some API for translating words not Localization. I think i will use Google Translate API

Comment: Oh, okay! All the best ahead! :)